# Case dashlets - what do they show and how can I edit them?

Tags: civicase, dashboard, dashlet

The CiviCase component includes two default "dashlets" that the user can place on their CiviCRM dashboard: 'My cases' and 'All cases'. It looks like these dashlets are showing only cases with upcoming scheduled activities. The documentation indicates that an upcoming window of 14 days is used for the main Case Dashboard displays, so I'm guessing that the same parameter applies for these dashlets.

How can I edit the configuration of these dashlets? I can't find any UI for this task, and so far I've not been able to identify any of the pre-existing report templates that can generate anything that looks like these dashlets.

Answer (score 3):

Graham, you can not really configure these dashlets, they are not based on existing CiviCRM reports but code specifically. We have just created a fair number of CiviCase reports (working on one as we speak :-), you would probably have to create/get someone to create a custom version of the dashlets or possibly even a custom report if it would make sense.

Comment: Thanks @ErikH. I assumed that this was likely to be the case, but thought I'd ask anyway. You never know.

Answer (score 0):

has anybody been able to edit the code for the 'My Cases' dashlet?

It is confusing for users who expect it to show their cases, but it is looking at the ones with scheduled activity only.

I have created a separate report for this, but the 'My cases' dashlet still shows up in the dashboard configuration.